# How to use Location Listener with syncadapter?

Tags: android, gps, android-syncadapter

How to use location listener with syncadapter here is my doubt i need to update User location in background for every 30 mins so i planned to use syncadapter which runs in regular interval here when application is in background am not getting latitude and logitude value instead am getting exception like null pointer where i get latitude and longitude is it a bad way or is there any better way than this (Note: Am using syncadapter in my app so am making use of that syncadapter ) can anyone share their ideas here let me post what i have tried so far:

```
Here is the Location listener class:
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class cSyncLocation implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    // =======================================================
    // private vars
    // =======================================================
    private GoogleApiClient moGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest moLocationRequest;
    private Location moCurrentLocation;
    private static final int kTIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS = 2500;
    Context context;

    // =======================================================
    // public static vars
    // =======================================================

    // =======================================================
    // public methods
    // =======================================================

    public void Start(Context oContext) {
        context=oContext;
        if (moGoogleApiClient == null) {
            moGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(oContext)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        if (moLocationRequest == null) {
            moLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

            moLocationRequest.setInterval(1);
            moLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1);
            moLocationRequest.setInterval(1);
            moLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        }
        // Start the connection
        if (moGoogleApiClient != null) {
            if (!moGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() && !moGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
                moGoogleApiClient.connect();
            else if (moCurrentLocation == null)

                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(moGoogleApiClient, moLocationRequest, this);

        }
    }

    public void Stop() {
        if (moGoogleApiClient != null && moGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(moGoogleApiClient, this);
        if (moGoogleApiClient != null)
            moGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    public Location GetLocationBlocking(Context oContext) throws InterruptedException {
        if (moCurrentLocation == null) {
            int intTimeout = kTIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS;
            Start(oContext);
            while (intTimeout > 0) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                intTimeout -= 100;
            }
            Stop();
        }

  //      String lat=String.valueOf(moCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
    //    String longt=String.valueOf(moCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
//        Toast.makeText(oContext,"Lat"+lat+"long"+longt,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return moCurrentLocation;

    }

    // =======================================================
    // Location API Events
    // =======================================================

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location oLocation) {
        if (oLocation != null) {
            moCurrentLocation = oLocation;
        }
    }

    // =======================================================
    // Google API Connection Events
    // =======================================================


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // Connected to Google Play services! The good stuff goes here.
        if (moGoogleApiClient != null) {

            Location oLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(moGoogleApiClient);
            if (oLocation != null)
                moCurrentLocation = oLocation;
            else
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(moGoogleApiClient, moLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result)
    {
        String errmessage=result.getErrorMessage();
        Log.d("errormesage",errmessage);
    }
```

Here in onPerformSyncmethod am using like this:

```
   cSyncLocation cSyncLocation=new cSyncLocation();
            try {
                Location loc=cSyncLocation.GetLocationBlocking(getContext());
                if(loc==null){
                    Log.e("no value","no value");
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("lat", String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()));
                    Log.d("long", String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Is it the efficient way i need to location details even during phone in locked state how it can be done..